# which kindle supports remote factory reset?

Tags: kindle, security

I have an old Paperwhite and I freak out every time I almost lose it.  Kindles are very personal.  Under my device options on Manage My Kindle I can only deregister it, which prevents people from buying books from it but, as I understand it, leaves all content on the device.  Does a Kindle e-reader model currently exist that allows for Remote Factory Reset?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently is it not possible to remotely factory reset any Kindle device.

The best you can do is de-register the device that has been lost, as you've mentioned.

[This Link](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201755180) outlines what you should do if you lose your device or if it is stolen, but again, it only suggests de-registering the device